# How does negating a matrix affect its eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on the following problem:
"If $Ax = \lambda x$, find an eigenvalue and an eigenvector of $e^{At}$ and also of $-e^{-At}$."

So far, I have figured that $e^{\lambda t}$ will be an eigenvalue of  $e^{At}$, and that $A$ has the same eigenvector matrix as $e^{At}$, so $x$ will be an eigenvector for  $e^{At}$.

However, I am a bit stuck on the $-e^{-At}$ part. I know that $e^{-At}$ is the inverse of $e^{At}$, so I think that means $\frac{1}{e^{\lambda t}}$ would be an eigenvalue for simply $e^{-At}$... but how do I find the eigenvalue for $-e^{-At}$? And how would I find an eigenvector?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to relate the equation $Ax = \lambda x$ to $(-A)y = \mu y$.

Comment: I don't really understand how to go from here. μ is an eigenvalue for -A, and y is an eigenvector... Now what?

Comment: @kmahar: You *relate the two equations*. And through that relationship, your knowledge of the full solution space to $Ax = \lambda x$ for $(\lambda, x)$ will be related to the full solution space to $(-A)y = \mu y$ for $(\mu, y)$.